# In Tensorflow, what is the difference between a Tensor and a TensorArray

Tags: tensorflow

I came accross TensorArray in Tensorflow's documentation: [TensorArray](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorArray#top_of_page)

However, I don't get what would be the use cases of TensorArray.

Comment: An array of Tensors

Comment: A use case can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43853600/3552975

Comment: @fabrizioM tensors can also be array of tensors?